# sqlite write error on attempt to read

Tags: c++, sqlite

I received this error when trying to SELECT from a sqlite database that I had opened with a read-only connection:

```
attempt to write a readonly database
```

What would cause a **write** error on a read attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly after posting this question, I realized there was a journal file left in the same directory as the db file:

```
mydb.sqlite
mydb.sqlite-journal
```

It had apparently been created by sqlite at some point, and sqlite was trying to use it to repair the database, and failing due to the read-only connection.  In my case, the journal file was old and irrelevant.  Removing the journal file allowed me to open a read-only database connection to the file and successfully perform SELECTs.